# Gradle or Gradle-Experimental for NDK projects?

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-experimental

Given the recent updates I'm a little lost on what I should be using now.

I have been using `gradle-experimental` successfully but it still misses some of the build options default gradle has.

The `gradle-experimental` documentation has not been updated so it gives the impression that it is still necessary for ndk projects, but given how google do documentation it could just be out of date.

Any light cast on this would be very welcome and let me rest easy.

Thanks